# Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Nodes of type 'a' may not be inserted inside nodes of type 'LI'

Tags: javascript, html

I just started to learn Javascript, and I'm trying to append anchor tag inside the li tag.

```
const li = document.createElement("li")
const Anchor = document.createElement("a")
Anchor.href = "index.html"
li.appendChild(Anchor)
```

This was how I did it. But when I run this,

"Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Nodes of type 'a' may not be inserted inside nodes of type 'LI'."

this error came out.  How can I fix it?

Comment: `"a"` is an element - your trying to use it as an attribute, an attribute would be, `href`, `type` (on inputs) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to `create` an element (`a`)

```
const li = document.createElement("li")
const Anchor = document.createElement("a")

// SET attribute 
// Anchor.href = "index.html"
// OR 
const linkHref = document.createAttribute("href");
linkHref.value = "index.html";
Anchor.setAttributeNode(linkHref);


li.appendChild(Anchor)
```